# Data inserted from datagridview not updated in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I'm still adjusting to the vb.net environment so I want to ask a question..

I have my code here:

```vb
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim connstr As String = "server=supertelco\sqlexpress; database=testdb; user= sa; password=sa;"

    cmdconn = New SqlConnection
    cmd = New SqlCommand
    cmdconn.ConnectionString = connstr 'sqlstr
    cmd.Connection = cmdconn
    cmdconn.Open()

    Dim period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated As String
    For i As Integer = 0 To Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1

        With Me.DataGridView2.Rows(i)

            If IsDBNull(.Cells(0).Value()) OrElse .Cells(0).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(0).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                period = ""
            Else
                period = .Cells(0).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(1).Value()) OrElse .Cells(1).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(1).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                VOUCH_AMT = "0"
            Else
                VOUCH_AMT = .Cells(1).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(2).Value()) OrElse .Cells(2).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(2).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                INDIVIDUAL_AMT = "0"
            Else
                INDIVIDUAL_AMT = .Cells(2).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(3).Value()) OrElse .Cells(3).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(3).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                check_no = ""
            Else
                check_no = .Cells(3).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(4).Value()) OrElse .Cells(4).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(4).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                D_MAILED = ""
            Else
                D_MAILED = .Cells(4).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(5).Value()) OrElse .Cells(5).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(5).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                DIR_NO = ""
            Else
                DIR_NO = .Cells(5).Value()
            End If
            If IsDBNull(.Cells(6).Value()) OrElse .Cells(6).Value() Is Nothing OrElse .Cells(6).Value().ToString().Trim() = "" Then
                who_updated = ""
            Else
                who_updated = .Cells(6).Value()
            End If



        End With

        cmd.CommandText = "insert into tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY(period, vouch_amt, individual_amt, check_no, d_mailed, dir_no, who_updated)values" & _
            "('" & period.Replace("'", "''") & "'," & VOUCH_AMT & "," & INDIVIDUAL_AMT & ",'" & check_no.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & D_MAILED.Replace("'", "''") & "', '" & DIR_NO.Replace("'", "''") & "','" & who_updated.Replace("'", "''") & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Saved")
    Next
    cmdconn.Close()

End Sub
```

so yeah, all code works fine except the updates in SQL Server. I wonder why the changes I made in dgv was not being reflected in the database after clicking the save button? Could someone help me about this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Where to begin?  Firstly, don't ever use string concatenation to insert values into SQL code.  Always use parameters.  To learn why and how, go here:

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html

Comment: Secondly, I would strongly recommend populating a DataTable with your data and saving the lot in a batch with a data adapter, e.g.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872-Retrieving-and-Saving-Data-in-Databases&p=3112830&viewfull=1#post3112830

If you're going to use a DataTable though, why not create one at the outset and bind it to the grid?  That way, you don't need any code to transfer the data from the grid to the DataTable.  It's all done for you.

Comment: Regardless, with your current code, I don;t see how it's possible for the code to work fine and not insert the records.  If that ExecuteNonQuery call is made then it must either succeed or fail.  Does it succeed and, if so, what value does it return?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yea. executenonquery, it does succeed. but no value was inserted in the database whenever i insert a data from datagridview.

Comment: Please answer the question that I actually asked.  If ExecuteNonQuery succeeds then it returns a value.  What is that value?

Comment: btw, to give you a heads up this table (BILLHISTORY) was called from another select statement which part of the program, all details in this table is from 1 user only.

Comment: if the value you're asking for is based from above. the value that it returns is msgbox "saved".. and it loops depending on how many rows that the table has. for example.the user i selected has 3 rows. therefore it will loop 4times.. anyway i could explain this more extensively if you care to chat(skype: magulo_id_ko) im really interested on the parameters stuff for i dont have any knowledge about it, and i don't know where how to transform my code into parameters.

Comment: We shouldn't have to explain to you what the return value of a function is.  I'm not talking about what you display.  I'm talking about the actual value returned by the ExecuteNonQuery method.  It's a number.  What is that number?!

Comment: i see it returns a value of -1. but there's no changes being made. when i look up at the database, i'm sorry for i am really new to this environment. :/

Comment: That's very strange.  The only way I would think that that could happen with an INSERT statement is if there was a trigger on that table and an error occurred in its execution.  Is that a possibility?  Regardless, I would start by getting rid of that ugly code that builds the SQL and use parameters, as is the proper way.

Comment: aww man.. :D did i mention that the datagridview content (ebd_billhistory)  was called from another select statement from another form?           cmd.CommandText = "select  period, VOUCH_AMT, INDIVIDUAL_AMT, check_no, D_MAILED, DIR_NO, who_updated, year_student from tobee.EBD_BILLHISTORY where CLAIM_NO like '" + claimno.ToString + "'"
        
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da = New SqlDataAdapter
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)
        frmEb.DataGridView2.DataSource = dt
        cmdconn.Close()

Comment: as u can see above, its a command button sub(SAVE) for the changes that i will do within the datagridview,  so all changes that i created will be saved to the databas. :/

Comment: hey @jmcilhinney i got these codes working now, but the result is not what i want to happen.. it is the update is wat i am trying to do then.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to copy the value cmd.CommandText has before you call ExecuteNonQuery to the clipboard and execute it in Sql Server Management Studio ... and see what happens (error messages) ... apart from this you should think about using SqlParameters ...

Comment: my professor advised me to use dt.acceptchanges() method. however, i don't know how to implement such method. sorry for silly answer noob programmer here. :/

Comment: I suggested executing the command in management studio just to find out if the command you've created dynamically works at all ... AcceptChanges doesn't do anything with the database ... it just resets the state of the rows in your datatable ... so it makes sense to call that function after your for loop ...

Comment: ... but it would be better to use a SqlDataAdapter which does all that automatically ...

Comment: yeah. i checked the commandtext and it works! but in another row, i see my error now. thank you :) all i need to do now is re build a new method for inserting a new data in the same record